# asymmetric blending/color interpolation that preserve whiteness

Tags: python, colors, blending, color-space

I'm using a software that is doing a kind of weird color interpolation. I find it very pleasant as it seems to preserve the whiteness of the input image in a better way than if I'm using a naive alpha blending interpolation in the sRGB space:

```py
white = np.ones((1,3), dtype=np.float32)
blue = (white * np.array([0, 0, 1])).astype(np.float32)
white * alpha + (1 - alpha) * blue
```

For these we don't want to read everything. Here are the main results I want to replicate:

Basic input image:
[image]

Output from the software if I use a black overlay (0, 0, 0) a gradient and a relightment set to 50%. Basically it is almost like if I have a mask from dark (0, 0, 0) to grey (127, 127, 127) set on my black overlay:
[image]

Now, here where it gets tricky. If I have a red overlay (1, 0, 0), a gradient and a relightment set to 50%, I got this:
[image]

So here, it is not just like if I set the mask of my overlay with my gradient (you can tried it or use Photoshop and you'll see there is something more to it...)

**Note**: The gradient should be the same if both experiments.

**Further informations**:

I want to replicate the results of the software and do my own script in python so that I can process a big bash of image.

Here are some output I got from using the software:

```
10% of blue (0, 0, 1) and 90% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.94117647 0.90980392 1. 
20% of blue (0, 0, 1) and 80% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.8745, 0.8335, 0.996  
30% of blue (0, 0, 1) and 70% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.80784314 0.72941176 1. 
  
10% of red (1, 0, 0) and 90% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 1, 0.9254902, 0.90980392  
20% of red (1, 0, 0) and 80% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 1, 0.8509, 0.8156  
30% of red (1, 0, 0) and 70% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.99607843, 0.76862745, 0.7254902  
  
10% of green (0, 1, 0) and 90% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.94117647, 0.99607, 0.92941176  
20% of green (0, 1, 0) and 80% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.8745, 1, 0.84705  
30% of green (0, 1, 0) and 70% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.81176471, 0.99607843, 0.78039216  
 
0% of black (0, 0, 0) and 100% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 1, 1, 1  
10% of black (0, 0, 0) and 90% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.89803922, 0.89803922, 0.89803922  
20% of black (0, 0, 0) and 80% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.79607843, 0.79607843, 0.79607843  
30% of black (0, 0, 0) and 70% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.79607843, 0.70196078, 0.70196078  
40% of black (0, 0, 0) and 60% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.60392157, 0.60392157, 0.60392157   
50% of black (0, 0, 0) and 50% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.50588235, 0.50588235, 0.50588235
```

for example the first line means:
If I take 10% of the blue (and 90% of the white ?) the output of the software in the rgb colorspace is: [0.94117647 0.90980392 1. ] which look a bit weird as the red and green channel go down by an asymmetric amount...

I've tried several things. Like converted the color in HSV, HSL, LAB, Luv using OpenCV but I cannot find a real "linear interpolation" in these spaces. The most promising spaces seem to be **LAB** or **Luv** since we can see a shift that is almost linear but it is not and thus instead of preserving the whiteness, it shifts to magenta if my overlay is blue for example

Here are some values:

```
blue in rgb colorspace is [255, 0, 0], in LAB: [82, 207, 20]
white in rgb colorspace is [255, 255, 255], in LAB: [255, 128, 128]
```

And now the software gives me:

```
10% of blue (+90% of white?) in LAB space: [238, 135, 118]
20% of blue (+80% of white?) in LAB space: [221, 141, 108]
30% of blue (+70% of white?) in LAB space: [202, 149,  97]
40% of blue (+60% of white?) in LAB space: [185, 156,  86]
50% of blue (+50% of white?) in LAB space: [169, 163,  76]
```

So, we can see it looks almost linear it that spaces but it is still insufficient.
For example the lightness seems to be almost linear: 255 * 0.8 + 82 * 0.2 = 220.4 if we take a linear interpolation between the lightness of the white and the blue in LAB space. And the software gave us: **221**. So it's quite good but actually this does not always hold:
For example for the **a** channel: 128*0.8 + 207 * 0.2 = 143.8 while the software gave use **141**.

It could have been due to rounding, but actually with float32 we can see a bigger difference.

The things that is strange is that the transformation of the software is actually linear in the rgb color space when we are using grayscale image:

```
0% of black (0, 0, 0) and 100% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 1, 1, 1  
10% of black (0, 0, 0) and 90% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.89803922, 0.89803922, 0.89803922  
20% of black (0, 0, 0) and 80% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.79607843, 0.79607843, 0.79607843  
30% of black (0, 0, 0) and 70% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.79607843, 0.70196078, 0.70196078  
40% of black (0, 0, 0) and 60% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.60392157, 0.60392157, 0.60392157   
50% of black (0, 0, 0) and 50% of white (1, 1, 1) give: 0.50588235, 0.50588235, 0.50588235
```

Does someone has any clue of what kind of blending/interpolation it could be?

**Note*: for a **low** or a **high** percentage value **only**, the result looks a bit like "Photo filter" in photoshop but it is not really this and also nobody knows how "photo filter" works in Photoshop (I've seen replication in Imagemagick, Photopea, ... but it is far from the result of Photoshop)

I hope an expert of colorscience could give me and hint :)

Thank you

Comment: Maybe your question is too long. not sure I followed all correctly. I think you were wrong at beginning: instead of looking HSL and other colour space, you may just need to linearize RGB ("unapplying gamma"), then you can add linearly lights, and then you need again gamma correct the result (the trick your RGB is in reality R*G*B*, you need always to check if formula go to gamma corrected or in linear space. Mixing light is an addition in linear space.)

Comment: Thank you for your proposition. I'm working with JPEG images, so, according to you, I should try to do a 1/2.2 gamma correction, do my x% "blending" and redo a 2.2 gamma correction?

Comment: Yes, mixing is done linearly, but our eyes see differently (so gamma correction is just efficient way to put more information into less bits)

Comment: I have tried with the gamma correction. It actually preserves more "lightness" of my background as desired but it also shrink the gradient transition and it appears too strong. So I guess there is something else to it. I have added some examples of what I'm trying to reproduce in the original post if you'd like to take a look